# How to read a Dependency property from a method

Tags: .net, wpf, methods, dependency-properties

XAML:

```
<my:Control ItemsSource="{StaticResource MySource}"  A="true" />
```

Assume a Control with a dependency property `A` with a default value `false`;
and a method to handle the Source Collection:

```
protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable oldValue, System.Collections.IEnumerable newValue) {}
```

in which you want to look at `A` and **readout its value** (which is true).
how would you ensure, that `A` is already initialized and has a given value?

Or how should this be done correctly ?

In my case A is something like AllowLateBinding ..

Could **coerce callback** help me?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the correctness but depending on your exact program logic, this might work:

```
protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue)
{
  if (IsInitialized)
  {
     DoWork(oldValue, newValue);
  }
  else
  {
    Initialized += (sender, e) => { DoWork(oldValue, newValue); };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by either supplying a default value in the definition of the DependencyProperty or you could set the default value in your classes constructor.

When you register a dependency property you can specify a PropertyMetadata object that gives the default value.

Look at the [DependencyProperty.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx) method for instance.

Comment: I think we ran in to misunderstanding, because I have a default value for A and it's false. Now if anyone uses the Control and set A="true" I have to be able to read true before I load the items into the control (spoken in the overridden ItemsSource Changed method)